# Remove duplicates from custom List object

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Summary: Remove duplicates from custom List of Lists

I tried using various existing methods to remove the duplicates from other stack overflow posts, some examples would be:

`var distinctWords = combinedList.Distinct().ToList();`

`fooArray.GroupBy(x => x.Id).Select(x => x.First());`

These solutions only filter based on 1 criteria, I need to remove the duplicates based on 2 criteria, if the year and id match then the duplicate needs to be removed. There can be different years that have the same id. I would like to do this without using MoreLINQ.

Model:

```
    public class data
    {
        public List<Inventory> inventory { get; set; }
        public List<LocationInventory> locationinventory { get; set; }

    }

    public class Inventory
    {
        public string name{ get; set; }
        public string year{ get; set; }
        public string id{ get; set; }
    }

    public class LocationInventory
    {
        public string location { get; set; }
        public List<Inventory> inventory { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller:

```
        public ActionResult getData(string[] Make, string[] Location)
        {
            data inv = new Models.data();

            //Make a list of the inventory lists
            inv.locationinventory = new List<LocationInventory>();

            //Split the Manufacturer and Location at the commas and store in new array
            string[] Make_Values = Make[0].Split(',');
            string[] Location_Values = Location[0].Split(',');

            //Get values for the tables
            var popData = new List<Inventory>();

            foreach (var Location_Value in Location_Values)
            {
                //Populate the data for each location
                //populateData returns a List<Inventory>
                popData = populateData(Make_Values, Location_Value.ToString());

                //Add the data to model with cooresponding location and inventory
                inv.locationinventory.Add(new LocationInventory{ location = Location_Value, inventory = popData });
            }

            return PartialView("Table", inv);
        }
```

View:

```
@{
    var inventories = Model.locationinventory.Select(x => x.inventory).Distinct().ToList();
    var list1 = new List<Project1.Models.Inventory>();
    var list2 = new List<Project1.Models.Inventory>();

    foreach (var inv in inventories)
    {
        if (list1?.Any() != true)
        {
            list1 = inv;
        }

        if (list1?.Any() != false)
        {
            list2 = inv;
        }

        var combinedList = list1.Union(list2);

        var test = combinedList.GroupBy(x => new { x.id, x.year }).ToList();

        <div>
            <table>                
                @foreach (var l in test)
                {
                    foreach (var m in l)
                    {
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <td>@m.name</td>
                                <td>@m.year</td>
                                <td>@m.id</td>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                    }
                }
            </table>
        </div>
    }

}
```

Current Results:

```
iphone 2019 x1234
iphone 2019 x1234
iphone 2020 x1234
iphone 2018 x1234
iwatch 2019 a4321
iwatch 2020 a4321
android 2020 n9876
android 2020 n9876
android 2019 n9876
```

Expected Results:

```
iphone 2019 x1234
iphone 2020 x1234
iphone 2018 x1234
iwatch 2019 a4321
iwatch 2020 a4321
android 2020 n9876
android 2019 n9876
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you need to implement a custom `IEqualityComparer<TSource>` to perform the comparation based on your criteria. Take a look at the [official documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinct?view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are somewhat near to what you need but not complete. After grouping you need to project only one row from each group like:

```
var uniqueInventory = combinedList.GroupBy(x => new { x.name,x.id, x.year })
                                  .Select(x => x.First())
                                  .ToList();
```

Now it will contain one item for each group and all will be unique entries.

Another way is to implement `IEqualityComparer` which can be passed in the `Distinct` method.

```
public class InventoryComparer: IEqualityComparer<Inventory>
{
    public override bool Equals(Inventory a, Inventory b)
    {
        return a.name == b.name
            && a.id == b.id
            && a.year == b.year;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode(Inventory inventory)
    {
        return inventory.id.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

and now we can use it like:

```
var uniqueInventory = combinedList.Distinct(new InventoryComparer());
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!!! This is exactly what I was trying to do, your solution worked perfectly!

Comment: That is pretty cool, I will go ahead and try the second method as well to learn some more.

Comment: @DotNetFullStack For completeness, also have a look at the [`DistinctBy()`](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/master/MoreLinq/DistinctBy.cs) method mentioned in the duplicate question's answers.